# axis2.databinding.ADBException: Unexpected subelement

Tags: java, soap, response, soapui, apache-axis

I'm writting a mock response for a SOAP Web Service and when I call the Web Service I get this Exception:

```
java.lang.Exception: org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException: Unexpected subelement relatedCharacteristicValues
```

I'm writting the response over the template that is generated from SOAPUI, so I don't understand how can exist an "Unexpected subelement" in the response.

Here's the unexpected element:

```
    <typ:relatedCharacteristicValuesList>
      <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
      <typ:relatedCharacteristicValues/>
   </typ:relatedCharacteristicValuesList>
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Just comment the Unexpected Elements and it works ,it was really weird that SOAP UI generates a response template with unexpected elements.